What is the origin of the hymn Namah Parvati Pataye?
Where is the below hymn found?
Namah Parvati Pataye.
Kindly quote from any scripture which you may be aware of.

https://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/articles/shiva-mahimnah-strotam?srsltid=AfmBOopBCxMaXpC5AoEV1ob8LTJ1ldFsM-CESwr8c_dNfdP83Muza03S something related to it

Thanks for sharing
